# Calling Javascript function on submit a form using struts2

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

I want to check certain conditions by using a javascript function in a jsp page when the user submits the form. I am using struts2.

I tried the following:

```
<s:submit action="finalSubmitOfServices" value="Submit" onclick="return fnConfirmSubmit()" />
```

and the javascript is like..

```
function fnCheckPendingValue()
    {
          //code
    }
```

But its not working, I am not sure how to solve this, Would really appreciate someone's help.

Thanks.

Comment: you are calling a different javascript function. LOL.

Answer (score 3):

First change your function name to `fnConfirmSubmit()` as Andrea Ligios said. And still if its not working write your function in **onsubmit** of form. Hope you got it.